# Average time to load 1.5 GB Dataframe from pyspark on EMR to S3 or Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I'm using an EMR cluster with 1 Master (m5.2x large) and 4 core nodes (c5.2xlarge) and running a PySpark job on it which will join 5 fact tables 150 columns and 100k rows each and 5 small dimension tables 10 columns each with less than 100 records. When I join all these the resultant dataframe will have 650 columns and 420k records (approximately 1.5 GB of data). I need to load this dataframe into a big fact table on redshift.

Joining of the dataframes is taking less than a minute but loading this dataframe to S3 or Redshift is taking approximately **6 minutes** which I think is pretty high. Need suggestion or guidance from experts if this time is normal or can still be tuned?

I tried loading with partitions, parquet files, loading into HDFS and then using S3discp to s3 and then to redshift. All implementations are taking the same **6minutes** timeframe.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but maybe you should investigate the log in the final steps. Maybe it's doing some map-reduce operation or a spark action is performing when it writes to a file.

Comment: Thank you @Guilherme Ferreira. I digged into the logs and found that the query before the actual load is messing up with the times.

Answer (score 0):

The optimum way to load data in redshift is by using redshift jdbc connector.

When you write data on redshift using jdbc connector it creates a temp directory in s3. And runs a copy command internally to load data into your table.

Now how this is optimized?

So it internally divides the file equivalent to number of slices available in redshift cluster and each slice picks a part of file making it loading faster and parallel.

Alternatively you can divide the file by repartitioning and save it on emrfs then run copy command manually.

For all usage info visit [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Hey how sure are you about all this? JDBC doesn't use s3 and copy? however your link is to the databricks redshift connector - which is the correct answer. please can you edit your answer to clear that up and make it more correct?

Comment: If you look inside the binaries you will find how redshift writes works and also while writing using this connector it asks for iam role and temp dir of s3 which is used to unload the data and then you can also specify copy params...I hope you have gone through the documentation properly

Comment: I could able resolve this issue. The lazy evaluation of spark made me think a bit lazy. The actual time it is taking is to to run a huge sql query that joins the above mentioned 5 fact tables and 5 dimension tables (this is taking close to 5minutes to run). Loading into Redshift or S3 doesn't take much time (hardly 20sec for 650 columns and 420k records).

Comment: Please suggest me something here, I'm from a SQL and DWH backgound. Hence I have used a single SQL query to join all 5 facts and 5dimensions as I have to derive 650 columns out of this and I feel that a single properly formatted query would be easy to maintain in the future. Also another thread in my mind is suggestion to use core spark joins (Eg: df=a.join(b, a['id']=b['id'], how='inner')).. Which one would be the best/suggestible way to join these tables? Currently in my huge SQL Query I'm broadcasting the small dimensions and that helped to certain extent.

Comment: Well post it as a question and i'll be happy to help...can't explain it in comments...thanks

Comment: @ShubhamJain, I have created a new question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029473/etl-1-5-gb-dataframe-within-pyspark-on-aws-emr